# Swift get specific NSManagedObject from entity (core data)

Tags: swift, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext, xcdatamodel

I have an entity in my "`ProjName.xcdatamodel`" with the name "Questions". In this entity I have 5 attributes ("icehockey","volleyball","soccer",...), each with type `transformable`. Each row (attribute) will be filled with a NSMutableArray.
What I want to do is to get the value of a specific attribute in this entity. This is my code:

```
func readQuestionsFromCore(sport:NSString) -> NSMutableArray {
    var appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
    var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Questions")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    var results: NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!
    var qArr:NSMutableArray!
    if results.count > 0 {
        var res = results[0] as NSManagedObject
        qArr = res.valueForKey("\(sport)") as NSMutableArray
        return qArr
    } else {
        qArr = []
        return qArr
    }
}
```

This will ofcourse not work since I take out the first index of the results from the database (`results[0] as NSManagedObject`) and thus it will crash if that element is not the same as the valueForKey I'm looking for.

How do I get the one result row that I'm looking for? I.e. "soccer", or at least can I somehow loop through the results and compare the keys of each result row so it doesn't crash when I try with the wrong key? Like something like this:

```
for (res) in results as NSManagedObject {
   if(res.key == "soccer") {
      qArr = res.valueForKey("soccer") as NSMutableArray
      return qArr
   }
}
```

I hope I'm clear in my explanation!

Comment: Help would be really appreciated. I have searched on the internet bad havn't had any luck!

Comment: I think you need to add an NSPredicate to your "request".  You can then filter on which data you would like to receive back from the entity.  Take a look at this link for example: http://nshipster.com/nspredicate/

Comment: @KevinHorgan Will try when at home!

Comment: why are you not using a custom sub class for Questions entity? why does your entity has 5 attributes, instead of 2 i.e "sport" and "question", that way you can filter the results? any specific reasons

Answer (score 1):

the `valueForKey` method returns an optional, you can use `if let` as below

```
if let questionsArr = res.valueForKey("\(sport)") as? NSMutableArray {
    return questionsArr
} else {
    return []
}
```

This works in Xcode 6.3.2, but looks like you are using older one. If so update to latest one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I clearly understand what you are trying to achieve. But using next function(that using KVC) you can get a list of class properties and than check if the one you need is there:

```
func getPropertyList(#classToInspect: AnyObject.Type) -> [String]
{
    var count : UInt32 = 0
    let properties : UnsafeMutablePointer <objc_property_t> = class_copyPropertyList(classToInspect, &count)
    var propertyNames : [String] = []
    let intCount = Int(count)
    for var i = 0; i < intCount; i++ {
        let property : objc_property_t = properties[i]
        let propertyName = NSString(UTF8String: property_getName(property))!
        propertyNames.append(propertyName as String)
    }
    free(properties)
    println(propertyNames)

    return propertyNames
}
```